# SQL select query - How to recognize NULL values in CASE

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQL select query where I select columns from a table, some of which are in BLOB format. I want to display the BLOB column as either 'Yes' or 'No' based on if the column is null or not (if there is data or not).

I've tried using this case statement, however it always returns 'Yes', no matter if the value is null or not. How can I fix this?

```
select category,
description,
CASE maintenance
    when 1 then 'Yes'
    else 'No'
END maintenance,
submittedBy,
CASE image
    when NULL then 'No'
    else 'Yes'
END image
from Forms
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_case_expression): *If the base expression is NULL then the result of the CASE is always the result of evaluating the ELSE expression if it exists, or NULL if it does not.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of `NULL` must be checked with `IS` so rewrite you query to

```
select category,
description,
CASE maintenance
    when 1 then 'Yes'
    else 'No'
END maintenance,
submittedBy,
CASE when image IS NULL then 'No'
    else 'Yes'
END image
from Forms
```